# Managing Github PR across different organizations

Tags: git, github, project-management, pull-request

I am a member of different organizations within our corporate github. Each and every organizations have more than 10 repos and each one will have PR. I find it difficult to keep up will all the PR across repos and organizations.. Is there anyway that we can manage this PR more easily.

NOTE: I am not sure if this is the right place to ask this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bookmark a search for the content you want, which will show results across repos. For example, here's [a search for open issues assigned to you](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=state%3Aopen%20assignee%3Arajkumarts&type=Issues&ref=searchresults). (PRs are issues, but not all issues are PRs.)

If you need to build more advanced queries, see the [GitHub Issues API](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/).